# Creating folders and files in Parallel

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am currently on a project about document generation.
Given 100.000 customers I need to create a folder for customer and a file inside it.
Is it quicker to create all the folders in advance or create file and folders if not exists as I go along in the loop.
The reason I am asking is because I have noticed that programs the copy folders or back up data usually tend to create folders first and then copy contents into it.

any suggestions

Comment: Why don't you measrure it yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure (I don't have the timer comparisons setup), however I would assume doing both in the 1 iteration would be faster and cleaner. Assuming you want to verify that no folder/file creation failed you can create the directory and verify it created successfully using

```
var clientPath = @"C:\foo\bar";
if (Directory.Exists(clientPath)) continue;
if (Directory.CreateDirectory(clientPath).Exists)
```

and then you can do the same with a file before continuing to the next, if not then log it or handle it correctly.

This way you know that every folder will either be created with the correct files or it'll be logged and it will also only go through the iteration once, instead of twice to create the folders and then create the files.

This is only my take on the situation